# RapidMiner: Calculate document similarity

Tags: rapidminer

I am using Rapidminer to calculate similarity between documents. I am using this process from my **Java Application**.

[image]

This process calculates similarity of each document with every other document in the dataset. I dont want to compute similarity between every document. **I only want to compute similarity of one selected document with all the other documents.**

The **Process Document** gives me a word vector with their **tf-idf** scores.
The **Data to Similarity** calculates **Cosine Similarity** between these vecotors.

So basically I need to calculate the Cosine Similarity of the one selected document to every other document in the dataset.

Is it possible in RapidMiner? Any insight will be helpful. Thank you.

**EDIT:**
**ANSWER:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Cross Distances` operator would be better. It takes two inputs both of which are example sets. The first could be a list of features for all documents and the second could be the list of features for the single document. The result is a new example set with a distance calculation. If you sort this example set (the operator probably returns a sorted list already but just in case you could use `Sort`) to find this minimum and use `Filter Example Range` to select it, you will get the details of the nearest document.

Comment: When  I tried with this similar approach I'm getting question mark in the distance? Any suggestions on what to look for?

Comment: I suggest posting a new question with enough details to allow the problem to be reproduced.